# Modern pages: is it possible to bookmark headings to create anchor hyperlinks?

Tags: modern-pages

In the case of a very long page, what is the best approach to help people jumping to the right section? in the past we had anchored hyperlinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature has now been released. You can hover over a heading to copy the anchor link (format: [page url].#heanding-name)

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/33253909-anchor-links-or-collapsing-sections

Comment: Note: you create the anchor by using any of the Heading styles (H1, H2, etc.) in a Text web part, then hover over the link icon to get the URL.

Comment: As far as I see, this option is for SPO only, not for SP 2019 on-premise. Or have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

Mikael Svenson build a modern script editor web part to make this anchors possible in Modern Sites:
[Creating anchor link scrolling on a modern page using the Modern Script Editor Web Part](https://www.techmikael.com/2018/01/creating-anchor-link-scrolling-on.html)

Comment: thanks, how do I 'download' this web part? I have downloaded another one but it was a compact file with sppkg extension, how do I 'take' this tool and deploy it to my tenancy?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no easy one file download. You have to build this web part on your own. This web part is part of the SharePoint Framework Client-Side Web Part Samples, so you can use the following page to get started: [link](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts) But this is just the tip of the iceberg, you may follow this link to setup everything you need: [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)